# Windows 7 Home Basic partitioning

Tags: windows, partitioning

There is a problem with a partitioning process.
Firstly, I've installed Acronis Disk Director Suite and in manual mode I've started to create a new partition.
My notebook had 3 partitions: main partition of ~300Gb with Windows installed, unknown "System" partition with "boot" flag of ~1.5Gb and recovery partition of ~8Gb.
So I tried to create a new partition using the free space from the first one. After rebooting Acronis started to work, created a new partition and started to replace "HDDRECOVERY" partition. During this process, notebook had been shutdown (it was plugged into the socket) and after turning on, I noticed the next: after turning on and booting BIOS, the laptop is going to reboot again and again and again.
Any ideas?
P.S.: sorry for the very muddled description

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a Windows CD and repair or reinstall.

Comment: forget to say. I have only Ubuntu LiveCD at the moment.

Comment: So get a Windows disc. Angus has the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this not a place to ask your question.

I think one of the reason:

Initial process of your recovery will remove your existing boot manager after copying data to temp. during that time your system got shutdown. Well I thing your boot manager not found now. Please refer here for more info **[HERE](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7hardware/thread/094b4b6d-c632-4831-9be6-b6d86025780d)**